Is there a way to run checkout step with elevated permissions?
Right now we do the following step in our YAML file:
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
    persistCredentials: True

However, we receive the following error(s) for some files/folders it's trying to clean:
warning: failed to remove Source/xxx/yyy/bin/Release/zzz/foldername: Permission denied

But only on 6 folders but not the rest. When trying locally, I need to run Windows Explorer in admin mode and then I can manually delete these files from my local build etc. When I run git clean locally, I get the same message as above.
So how can I run that checkout step with elevated permissions/as admin mode?

The error indicates the agent user doesn't have permission to remove the files.

So how can I run that checkout step with elevated permissions/as admin mode?

You cannot use elevated permission user to run the checkout step, but need to change the agent user who is running the agent.
To check the user who is running the agent, you can add whoami command in bash task, run the pipeline to check the username output.
steps:
  - bash: |
      whoami


Then you can uninstall and reconfigure the agent with the admin user, so that it will run as agent admin user, who can remove the files.
For example with Ubuntu self-hosted agent:
uninstall the agent:
./config.sh remove

On agent machine terminal, switch to the admin user:
su - adminuser

Reconfigure the agent with ./config.sh, it will setup the agent with admin user.
Or you can add the current agent user in admin user group on the agent machine, so that it will grant the permission to remove the files.
